# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database “mydb” failed: FATAL: database “postgres” does not exist

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

this is my shell script connecting to postgres and trying take the backup using pg_dump.

running on MAC terminal.

shell script:[image]

```
but getting this error :
```

pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "psql -U postgres -At -c "$query" postgres" failed: FATAL:  database "psql -U postgres -At -c "$query" postgres" does not exist

please help me

Comment: i have updated the error message pelase check

Comment: Did you really used backticks, or were it single quotes, actually?

Comment: single quotes only..

Comment: Should have been backtics (that is the key below the ESC key)

Comment: change to `for line in $(psql -U postgres -At -c "$query" postgres); do`

Comment: And this is a good reason, to **post the actual source** for the script, not some image with different code. (which looks correct, BTW)